# Unexpected number of fully connected neurons after padding with stride in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to replicate the procedure of this paper [(Re-)Imag(in)ing Price Trends](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3756587), that trains a 2dCNN based on OHLC charts. They have images of different dimensions (32x15, 64x60 and 96x180) corresponding to 5, 20 and 60 daily bars and thus three dimension-specific architectures. But I end up with a different number of neurons compared to them in the fully connected layer for the 20day horizon (64x60)...

I followed the specification of their architecture that can be summarised as:

- Number of blocks: (32x15): 2; (64x60):3 and (96x180):4
- Fixed number of filters in 1st block: 64, else number doubles each convolutional block
- 5x3 (kernel size) convolutional filters (for all image types)
- 2x1 max-pooling filters (for all image types)
- vertical stride of 1, 3, and 3 (only in first layer) for 32x15, 64x60 and 96x180 respectively
- vertical dilution rate of 1, 2, and 3 (only in the first layer) for 32x15, 64x60 and 96x180 respectively
- padding such that output has SAME dimension as the image itself

I suspect that my issue has something with the workaround for padding="same" in pytorch with asymmetric strides. Since strides can be >1, I went for the Conv2d workaround provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73332370).

According to their paper (see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8igeg.png)), the CNN for 20 days horizon (64x60) should end up having 46080 neurons in FC layer.
Below is the code for my architecture that gets the following error when resizing.

> RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 46080]' is invalid for input of size 30720:

Clearly, the dimensions are incorrect and sensitive to changing the padding calculations. I cannot seem to get this right, not sure how I would else figure out padding for each block in each specific model... Hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import math
from functools import reduce
from operator import __add__
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Conv2dSame(nn.Conv2d):
"""
https://github.com/pytorch/captum/blob/optim-wip/captum/optim/models/_common.py#L144 
"""

    def calc_same_pad(self, i: int, k: int, s: int, d: int) -> int:
        pad = max((math.ceil(i / s) - 1) * s + (k - 1) * d + 1 - i, 0)
        return pad

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        
        ih, iw = x.size()[-2:]
        kh, kw = self.weight.size()[-2:]
        pad_h = self.calc_same_pad(i=ih, k=kh, s=self.stride[0], d=self.dilation[0])
        pad_w = self.calc_same_pad(i=iw, k=kw, s=self.stride[1], d=self.dilation[1])

        if pad_h > 0 or pad_w > 0:
            x = F.pad(
                x, [pad_w // 2, pad_w - pad_w // 2, pad_h // 2, pad_h - pad_h // 2]
            )
        return F.conv2d(
            x,
            self.weight,
            self.bias,
            self.stride,
            self.padding,
            self.dilation,
            self.groups,
        )

class Net20(nn.Module): 
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            Conv2dSame(1, 64, kernel_size=(5,3), stride=(3,1), dilation=(2,1)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 1)) 
        )
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            Conv2dSame(64, 128, kernel_size=(5,3)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 1))
        )
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
            Conv2dSame(128, 256, kernel_size=(5,3)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d((2, 1))
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Linear(46080, 1), 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(-1,1,64,60)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = x.reshape(-1,46080) # FC neurons according to paper
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, torch doesn't support 'same' padding and you should implement it yourself for odd size with `F.pad`.

First I suggest you to inspect `MaxPool2D`. By default, the output of a 3x3 image by `MaxPool2D((2, 2))` is of shape 1x1 (forgetting borders) but you may expect 2x2. Typically if your width starts to be odd you can have a problem. You can try to add `ceil_mode=True` argument (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803220/regarding-odd-image-dimensions-in-pytorch) for details).

Now regarding the padding calculation, you should note that there are many possible implementation for padding  because "same" padding is ambiguous in your case. I found an other implementation that also should mimic tensorflow behaviour (see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/67551)). It seems not to be exactly what you used so you can try it:

```py
class Conv2dSame(nn.Conv2d):

  def calc_same_pad(self, i: int, k: int, s: int, d: int) -> int:
    # (i + s - 1) // s instead of ceil(i / s)
    pad = max(0, ((i + s - 1) // s - 1) * s + (k - 1) * d + 1 - i)
    return pad

  def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    # ...
    pad_w, pad_h = self.calc_same_pad(...), self.calc_same_pad(...)
    w_odd, h_odd = pad_w % 2 == 1, pad_h % 2 == 1

    if w_odd or h_odd:
      # Add 1 padding now for odd size
      x = F.pad(x, [0, int(w_odd), 0, int(h_odd)])

    return F.conv2d(
      x,
      kernel_size=self.weight,
      bias=self.bias,
      stride=self.stride,
      padding=(pad_w // 2, pad_h // 2),  # add the rest of the padding here
      dilatation=self.dilation,
      groups=self.groups,
      )
```

Basically if for instance `i = s + 1 = 4` the two methods don't return the same thing. I let you explore that.

Notes:

- `padding` argument in `Conv2dSame` has no effect (that's logical as the padding is calculated on the fly)
- the padding in two steps should be similar to what you did with `[pad_w // 2, pad_w - pad_w //2, ...]` but I keep it to respect the original code (in case of there is a strange behaviour in `Conv2D` but I don't think so)

Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was indeed the MaxPool2d without ceil_mode that caused the problem.